How to design porch swing so it doesn’t tip over?
I’m building a porch swing out of an old chair from a ski lift. The beam the chair hangs from will be 12 feet high. I currently have a design where the A-frame has an angle of 33 degrees. I am not going to anchor the swing to the ground as it will weigh about 400 pounds before anyone gets on it.
I don’t know how to make sure that a 33 degree angle is large enough to ensure that the swing won’t tip over when it’s swinging with three people on it. I have a degree in physics, but I don’t remember this in my classes.

it depends how high the three people swing.

So you draw an isosceles triangle 12 units high and with a vertex angle of 33°. Then you take your compasses and extend them to represent the length of the chain on which the seat hangs, and draw a circular arc.  If any part of the arc lies outside the footprint of the frame, then you may have cause to worry.  This simple analysis takes no account of any dynamic forces arising from the 400-lb swingers, but you're the one with the degree in physics! Me, I'd test it with 3 teenagers, they're usually fairly robust ...

With three teens, you want the legs anchored into concrete, no matter how wide the legs are.  The hold my beer guys are just trying to relive their teen lives.

Simplest fix may be to firmly attach the swing supports to the porch.

basically the people are sitting on the seat are exerting a normal force. so any time the seat is not between the legs the swing is potentially unstable.
